# Cannot save category Magento 2.3.6-p1

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.3.6-p1

i have a multiwebsite magento, one website work properly but for the other when i try to save a category i got an error :

> a Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() must be of the type string, array given, called in /home/www/budracing/www/releases/20210930133410/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from another module, mageplaza catalog permission, one of the module observer was causing the error.